# MongoDb schema desgin multi collections vs one collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I am faily new to NoSql,i am working on a project and need to use Nodejs with mongodb,
i read alot but can't seem to figure it out.The app will have categories and items with one to many relationship,should i use 1 collection where category object has an array of products.
or use 2 collections (category and products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are going to be a lot of *products* for a *category*, and you store the *category* with an array of *products*, there are high chances that it may become an unbounded array as the number of *products* increase for a *category*, and would impact the database's overall performance. It is always a better idea to [avoid having unbounded arrays](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-suggestions/avoid-unbounded-arrays/) in your schema. Thus, it would be better to have 2 collections, one for *category* and another for *products* (with a field called *categoryId*). You can read more about the best practices around modelling One-to-Many relationships [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).